# Blacklist Domains from Email Field + Correct Format

Tags: html, forms, field

I have a client that would like to blacklist 300+ competitor domains from being entered into their email fields on their HTML forms. They would like to also only accept emails in the format hello@domain.extension.

If an incorrect email is entered a rejection message should either appear immediately or after one presses submit.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: You start by choosing a scripting language to do this in. First that comes to mind is Javascript. This can be hacked. If you want to secure the form against that, you have to use a programming language that works on the server, like PHP. Next is learning the language, and then start coding.

Comment: I'm familiar with PHP and Javascript. I just don't know how exactly to approach this. I've already used pattern strings in my form fields, but that won't work for 300+ domains.